# c# direct equivalent of VB IsDate()

Tags: c#

I have a 'simple' requirement - a quick check to see if an object is a valid `DateTime` and, if not, return a known default date.

There are a number of alternative solution:

1. Use the VB function directly by adding a reference to the VB library - simple but adding an additional library to the solution feels like bloat
2. Using `DateTime.TryParse()` - need to convert to `object` to `string` first and don't need the result
3. `try catch` block around `Convert.ToDateTime()` - feels clumsy but simple

They each have different pros and cons and they all have overheads - have a missed a simpler solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `is` operator:

```
Object foo = new DateTime();

if( foo is DateTime dt )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "The date is: {0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dt );
    return dt;
}
else
{
    return someDefaultDate;
}
```

If you want the same behaviour as VB's `IsDate` function, add a call to `DateTime.TryParse` if the `is DateTime` check evaluates to false:

```
static DateTime GetDateOrDefault( Object o, DateTime defaultValue )
{
    if( o is DateTime dt )
    {
        return dt;
    }
    else if( DateTime.TryParse( o?.ToString(), out dt ) )
    {
        return dt;
    }
    else
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `is DateTime` will only return true if the object is a boxed DateTime, not if it's _convertable_ to DateTime like what VB's `IsDate()` does.

Comment: @41686d6564 The VB `Information.IsDate` method internally uses the same IL instruction (`isinst`) as C#'s `is` operator - the only difference is that `IsDate` also uses `DateTime.TryParse( obj.ToString() )`.

Comment: Yes, it checks if the input is null, then checks if it `is DateTime`, then uses `DateTime.TryParse()` in a "lenient way" (which is a habit of VB to be a little forgiving).